# Navigate to a tab of a tab control declared in a region with region manager

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a usercontrol that has a tab control. Within each tab i have some regions declared.

```
<TabControl Style="{DynamicResource HomeScreenTabControlStyle}">
            <TabItem Header="home"
                     Style="{DynamicResource HomeScreenTabItemStyle}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Name="BacklogPanel" Style="{DynamicResource FullLengthPanelStyle}"
                                prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.FullLeftBoxRegion}">

                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Name="ToDoPanel" Style="{DynamicResource HalfLengthPanelStyle}"
                                    prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.HalfTopBoxRegion}">

                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Name="MeetingPanel" Style="{DynamicResource HalfLengthPanelStyle}"
                                    prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.HalfBottomBoxRegion}">

                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel> 
                    <StackPanel Name="SprintPanel" Style="{DynamicResource FullLengthPanelStyle}"
                                prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.FullSecondLeftBoxRegion}">

                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Name="StoriesPanel" Style="{DynamicResource FullLengthPanelStyle}"
                                prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.FullRightBoxRegion}">
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="sprints"
                     Style="{DynamicResource HomeScreenTabItemStyle}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel Style="{DynamicResource FullLengthPanelStyle}"
                                prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.SprintBacklog}">

                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Style="{DynamicResource HalfLengthPanelStyle}"
                                    prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.PeopleOnSprint}">

                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel  Style="{DynamicResource HalfLengthPanelStyle}"
                                    prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.SprintDetails}">

                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Style="{DynamicResource FullLengthPanelStyle}"
                                prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.SprintTaskBacklog}">

                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel  Style="{DynamicResource FullLengthPanelStyle}"
                                prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.SprintMyTasks}">
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>

                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
```

Currently to navigate to this HomeScreenView im doing something like this...

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ContentRegion, new Uri("/HomeScreenView", UriKind.Relative));
```

Is there anything i can pass to the region manager so that it will set the Sprints Tab to be the tab navigated to, and not the home tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest possible way is to make views from those TabItems as well. And region from TabControl. So You navigate to your View with TabControlRegion and probably in OnNavigateTo method from INavigationAware interface you would navigate to HomeTabItemView and SpritsTabItemView

```
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TabControlRegion, new Uri(ViewNames.HomeTabItemView, UriKind.Relative));
        this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TabControlRegion, new Uri(ViewNames.SpritsTabItemView, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

TabControlRegion

```
<Window x:Class="Onii.Vespa.UI.Shell.Desktop.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Regions="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism" MinHeight="640" MinWidth="820" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid Height="Auto">   
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Top" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="TabControlRegion" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Margin="0,3,0,20" />
</Grid>
```

Views will be like this:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.HomeTabItemView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <StackPanel Name="BacklogPanel" Style="{DynamicResource FullLengthPanelStyle}"
      prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.FullLeftBoxRegion}">

       </StackPanel>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
           <StackPanel Name="ToDoPanel" Style="{DynamicResource HalfLengthPanelStyle}"
          prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.HalfTopBoxRegion}">

           </StackPanel>
           <StackPanel Name="MeetingPanel" Style="{DynamicResource HalfLengthPanelStyle}"
          prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.HalfBottomBoxRegion}">

           </StackPanel>
       </StackPanel> 
       <StackPanel Name="SprintPanel" Style="{DynamicResource FullLengthPanelStyle}"
      prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.FullSecondLeftBoxRegion}">

       </StackPanel>

       <StackPanel Name="StoriesPanel" Style="{DynamicResource FullLengthPanelStyle}"
      prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.FullRightBoxRegion}">
       </StackPanel>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Don't forget to set TabItems Header text. You can do it in shered TabItemStyle

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Content.DataContext.TabHeaderText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    ...
```

And after that easily add TabHeaderText property to your ViewModels for views displayed within TabControlRegion.

Comment: Thanks for this, i actually solved this with implementing the Inavigation aware interface in the code behind of the home screen, then reading out the params when OnNavigatedTo is called, then just set the active tab based on a param passed in from the region manager.